# How to exclude null value when applying Over function in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

This is the date I have now,

```
Student    Original End Date    Start Date
A            3/22/2018          3/23/2018
A            3/22/2018          3/23/2018
A                               3/23/2018
A                               3/23/2018
A            5/20/2018          5/21/2018
A            5/20/2018          5/21/2018
B            2/1/2018           3/1/2018
B                               3/1/2018
B            2/1/2018           2/2/2018
C            3/1/2018           3/2/2018
C            3/1/2018           3/2/2018
```

And I would like to get result like this,

```
Student     Original End Date   Start Date  Result
A             3/22/2018         3/23/2018   TRUE
A             3/22/2018         3/23/2018   TRUE
A                               3/23/2018   TRUE
A                               3/23/2018   TRUE
A             5/20/2018         5/21/2018   TRUE
A             5/20/2018         5/21/2018   TRUE
B             2/1/2018          3/1/2018    FALSE
B                               3/1/2018    FALSE
B             2/1/2018          2/2/2018    FALSE
C             3/1/2018          3/2/2018    TRUE
C             3/1/2018          3/2/2018    TRUE
```

I would like to have result returned as `True` if `Original End Date + 1 = Start Date` for each student. For example, `A`, although it has null in original end date, but the rest matches the logic, so all its results are `True`. `B`, it has null original end date, and only one of its `Original Start Date + 1 = Start Date`, therefore, all the `B` results should be `False`

Here is the Spotfire calculated fields' code I have now, but it does not return the results for the null value, and for `B`'s result, it has both `True` and `False`.

```
DateAdd('dd',1,Min([Original End Date]) over [Student]) = [Start Date]
```

I am wondering if I should add `case when` or `if` here? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Adriaan, the code I have now does not return the results for the null value, and for B's result, it has both True and False.

Comment: @Adriaan question added into the post

Comment: so for each student, it will be all TRUE or all FALSE?

Comment: Hi @scsimon Yes :) all TRUE or all FALSE